# Broken OTF file in p5

Tags: javascript, fonts, p5.js

When adding a custom font to my project, it bunches up to the left. There's no way from my -albeit brief- search to change the spread of the letters within the code. I could make a new text function every time I want a letter, but that would be extremely inefficient.
Here's some test code:
let newgroundsFont
function preload() {
newgroundsFont=loadFont("NewgroundsFont-Regular.otf")
}

```
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
    }
    
    function draw() {
      background(220);
      textFont(newgroundsFont)
      textSize(10)
      text("Hi! I'm a test!", 5, 20)
      textSize(20)
      text("Hi! I'm a test!", 5, 60)
      textSize(40)
      text("Hi! I'm a test!", 5, 120)
      textSize(80)
      text("Hi! I'm a test!", 5, 220)
      textSize(160)
      text("Hi! I'm a test!", 5, 390)
    }
```

But this is the result:

[image: Text moved to the left]

The URL for this project is this:
https://editor.p5js.org/TheDiamondfinderYT/sketches/EkaCD2jb6

And this is the font:
https://www.newgrounds.com/dump/download/f858f852e56f5dda50ae2aa869455495

*****THIS WILL INSTANTLY DOWNLOAD IT IN A ZIP*****

Comment: You could create an array of characters and then use something like this:textSize(10);  for(let x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
    text(str[x], 5*x + 30, 30); 
  } but I have no idea why that is necessary.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the font works as expected in Processing 4.08b in Java mode.

Comment: @apodidae I guess that's good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Try converting the font to fix compatibility

The font is not a standard compliant .otf (or CFF based Open Type).

It has a non standard 2048 units per em.
Typically used for truetype (open type) fonts – whereas CFF (otf) open types use 1000 units per em.

A quick fix would be to convert it to ttf/truetype via a tool like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org) – tested!

#### 2. Preload your font in HTML/CSS

I recently discovered this workaround ["Arabic font not showing correctly in p5.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72644831/arabic-font-not-showing-correctly-in-p5-js/72860918#72860918)

It also works in your use case:
Essentially you're loading the font via `@font-face` in css and
reference the font in p5.js by its (css) font-family name `textFont('NewgroundsFont')`.

[Example on https://editor.p5js.org](https://editor.p5js.org/herrstrietzel/sketches/u2KL0HABW)